# SetDate() to Calendar object to change time, changes the date back to 1970

Tags: java, android, date, datetime, calendar

So, I start getting the current time in a Calendar object named startTime

```
Calendar startTime = Calendar.getInstance();
Log.w(TAG, "CALENDAR BEFORE: " + startTime.getTime());
```

This works great, as my logs say that the time is the current one (i.e. Tue Nov 07 12:50:10 CST 2017).
However I need to get a time from a Preference option, which returns me something like this: "15:00". This is being stored in a String alarmPref

```
String alarmPref = preferences.getString(keyAlarm, "12:00");
Log.w(TAG, "AlarmReceiver: Alarm going to be set at: " + alarmPref);
```

Here is where it gets tricky, I change this String to a Date using a SimpleDateFormat with only hours and minutes (adding date stuff crashes).

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.getDefault());
```

And when I try to add this time to the Calendar object I created first (startTime) it changes the time to "Thu Jan 01 15:00:00 CST 1970", where I have the correct time but not date.

```
Date newDate = format.parse(alarmPref);
startTime.setTime(newDate);
Log.w(TAG, "CALENDAR AFTER SET: " + startTime.getTime());
```

I've been trying to fix this but haven't found the solution, nor similar problems.

Comment: Your Question is not clear. You want to alter a date-time by setting a specific time-of-day? And talking about irrelevant subjects such as  "alarmPref" and logs is an unwelcome distraction.

Comment: Even on Android it’s worth considering getting [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) so you can use [the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and skip the long outdated classes `Calendar` and `Date`. Certainly for non-trivial date-time operations like yours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your goal is to alter a date-time by setting a specific time-of-day…

## tl;dr

```
ZonedDateTime.of( 
    LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Chicago" ) ) ,  // Get the current date for a particular place on Earth.
    LocalTime.parse( "15:00" ) ,                       // Specify the time-of-day.
    ZoneId.of( "America/Chicago" )                     // Assign the intended zone to the resulting `ZonedDateTime` object.
)
```

## Issue

You are parsing a String representing a time-of-day as a date-time value. That parsing method assumes you want the first day since the [epoch reference date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)) of 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z. So you got 3 PM on January 1st of 1970. That is all correct documented behavior. But not what you intended.

## Solution

### Avoid legacy classes

Avoid the troublesome old date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java such as `Calendar`. These were supplanted years ago in Java 8 and Java 9 by the java.time classes. For earlier Android, see the last bullets below.

### Time zone

Specify your intended time zone. If omitted, the JVM’s current default time zone is implicitly applied. That default may change at any moment during runtime, and so is unreliable.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `CST` or `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Chicago" ) ;
```

A time zone is crucial in determining a date and time-of-day. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

```
ZonedDateTime zdtNow = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
```

### Time-of-day

For a time-of-day only value, without any date and without an time zone, use the `LocalTime` class.

```
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.parse( "15:00" ) ;
```

## Date-only + Time-of-Day

You want the same date but with another time-of-day. So extract the date-only portion, combine with the desired time-of-day while applying the intended time zone to get a new [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) object.

```
LocalDate ld = zdtNow.toLocalDate() ;
ZonedDateTime zdtTodayAtThreePm = ZonedDateTime.of( ld , lt , z ) ;
```

Tip: Generally best to do your logging, serializing, and data exchange in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) rather than a particular time zone.  For that use the `Instant` class. You can extract a `Instant` from a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
Instant instant = zdtTodayAtThreePm.toInstant() ;  // Always in UTC.
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: Good and thorough answer, thanks. How about `ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/Chicago")).with(LocalTime.parse("15:00"))`? What I like about is we need only mention the zone ID once.

Comment: @OleV.V. Yes, that works well too. I just like to show the pieces separately for clear demonstration.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get a fixed by doing this:

```
String alarmPref = preferences.getString(keyAlarm, "12:00");
Log.w(TAG, "AlarmReceiver: Alarm going to be set at: " + alarmPref);
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.getDefault());
Date newDate = format.parse(alarmPref);
//startTime.setTime(newDate);
startTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, newDate.getHours());
startTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, newDate..getHours());
startTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
Log.w(TAG, "CALENDAR AFTER SET: " + startTime.getTime());
```

Where I only set the HOURS and MINUTES (and seconds to 0), and the date remains the same. However the methods .getHours() and .getHours() are deprecated, is there a more fancy way to do this?

Comment: A more fancy way? Yes. `ZonedDateTime.of(      LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Chicago" ) ) ,     LocalTime.parse( "15:00" ) ,             ZoneId.of( "America/Chicago" )  )`

Comment: Using the deprecated methods of `Date` (which is in turn entirely outdated). This is in no way the solution I would recommend.

Comment: If you insist on using the outdated classes, you should at least use a second `Calendar` object for the time-of-day and copy the hours and minutes (and seconds and milliseconds) from it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problems here. You are asking the SimpleDateFormat to parse a Date, by only providing hours and minutes. It defaults the other fields which are missing from your input to the beginning of time, which is not what you expect. Apparently the developer who implemented SimpleDateFormat thought that this behavior is reasonable.

The workaround in which you set only the HOUR_OF_DAY and MINUTE looks good.